Add a variable to request URL in pre-request script
I have 2 Postman requests in a collection that the first request should run before the second request runs.
The first request is a POST request and it'll give you a messageId in the repsonse body,
    {
       "messageId": "test-abcdefg",
       "messageStatus": "PUSHED"
    }

and the second request is a GET request and it passes the messageId in the url,
https://abcd.com.au/stp/v1/aaa/abcd@account/{{messageId}}

So, in the second request I have added a placeholder in the url to pass the messageId.  and I've written a Pre-request script to run the first request and pass a value from it to the second request.
Here is my Pre-request script,


pm.sendRequest({
    url: 'url',
    method: 'POST',
    header: {
        'content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: {
            mode: 'raw',
            raw: [
                    { key: "key1", value: 'abcd' },
                    { key: "key2", value: '123456789' },
                    { key: "key3", value: 1 },
                    { key: "key4", value: 'abcd' }
            ]
    }
}, (err, res) => pm.variables.set("messageId", res.json().messageId));



But, I'm getting the following error,
There was an error in evaluating the Pre-request Script:Error: Unexpected token '<' at 2:1 <!DOCTYPE html> ^

What did I do wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Why are you using sendRequest instead of a fully fledged request.  Just have the POST request first, and in the tests tab, you parse the response and save the message ID to an environment or collection variable.  The GET request then doesn't need any special code.

My understanding of the above pre-request script tells me that the post request you are sending, is sending you an error HTML page, that's why it is not able to resolve the res.json().
Try changing
 raw : JSON.stringify([
                { key: "key1", value: 'abcd' },
                { key: "key2", value: '123456789' },
                { key: "key3", value: 1 },
                { key: "key4", value: 'abcd' }
          ])

If this doesn't work,
I would ask you to check the url that you are, sending in pre-request script or check body parameters that url requires. If those are as required, then check the Post API requirement for header type or authentication.
I hope this helps.

Pretty sure that the issue is just related to stringifying the body.
However, you could make the sendRequest more robust by adding a test or tests before you try and set the variable from the response.
pm.sendRequest({
    url: 'url',
    method: 'POST',
    header: {
        'content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: {
        mode: 'raw',
        raw: JSON.stringify([
            { key: "key1", value: 'abcd' },
            { key: "key2", value: '123456789' },
            { key: "key3", value: 1 },
            { key: "key4", value: 'abcd' }
        ])
    }
}, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        pm.test("Status code is 200", function () {
            pm.expect(res).to.have.status(200);
            pm.test("messageId exists", function () {
                let resJson = res.json();
                pm.expect(resJson.messageId).to.exist;
                pm.variables.set("messageId", resJson.messageId);
            });
        });
    }
});

